# Flask KeyError 400 Bad Request when trying to retrive data from a textarea after click on a button

Tags: python, html, flask

I have been looking everywhere for a solution and checked for most common things on similar questions here on stack overflow and other places and those who had similar questions didn't have any answers. I have no idea what I am missing but I can't get this to work. I simply want to retrieve the text from the texarea after I click on the button.

my html

```
<form action="{{ url_for('fetch') }}" id="main_form" methods="POST">
     <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-text">Text to synthesize</span>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="text"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-center" style="padding:25px">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" id="btnFetch" value="Synthesize into Audio">
     </div>
</form>
```

my python

```
@app.route('/TTS_page', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def TTS_page():
    print("You are on the worky page.")
    return render_template('TTS_page.html', txt = "")

@app.route('/fetch', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def fetch():
    text = "No post request was made."
    print("Button has been pressed.")
    if request.method == "POST":
        print("POST REQUEST MADE...")
        print(request.form["text"])
        text = request.form.get("text")
    return render_template('TTS_page.html', txt = text)
```

I aslo tried with `text = request.form("text")`

In the image below you can see that after clicking the button I do get the right "text" (in the adress bar), but the Flask side does not see it.
[image]

If I remove the `if request.method == "POST":` I get:

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser
> (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> KeyError: 'text'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2464, in **call** return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2450, in wsgi_app response = self.handle_exception(e) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1867, in handle_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise raise value File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 2447, in wsgi_app response = self.full_dispatch_request() File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1952, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.handle_user_exception(e) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1821, in handle_user_exception reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask_compat.py",
> line 39, in reraise raise value File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1950, in full_dispatch_request rv = self.dispatch_request() File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line
> 1936, in dispatch_request return
> self.view_functionsrule.endpoint File
> "F:\FASTProjects\Licenta\TTS-Web-App\backend.py", line 35, in fetch
> print(request.form["text"]) File
> "C:\Users\vladc.conda\envs\IOT\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\datastructures.py",
> line 442, in **getitem** raise exceptions.
> BadRequestKeyError(key) werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad
> Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could
> not understand. KeyError: 'text'

Comment: Try using `request.POST` instead of `request.form`.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 " AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'POST' "
That's what happens. Thing is `request.method` is never POST for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form action="{{ url_for('fetch') }}" id="main_form" method="POST">`

It works I just mistyped. It's `method="POST"` not `methods="POST"`